# Forwarding mail to alias in Postfix

Tags: postfix, email, forwarding

Currently I have setup Slicehost as my relayhost for mail. Postfix is my MTA. 
This is how I have configured forwarding:

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

my virtual file has:
abc@mydomain.com abc@gmail.com

But the mail is being forwarded as spam.
In case I send mail directly from abc@mydomain.com to abc@gmail.com it appears in the inbox,but the forwarding results in the mail ending in spam.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

At first guess, I'd say that joschi is on the right track...what's your $myorigin?

Or, perhaps the output of `postconf -n`?

Comment: +1, always post "postconf -n" when troubleshooting postfix.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be caused by SPF or similar mechanisms. When your MTA forwards the mails to GMail, the SPF records of the original sender's domain do not match your domain and thus GMail thinks it is spam. The proper solution to this (given SPF is really the problem) would be using [SRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme).

See the SPF FAQ on [forwarding](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Forwarding) for details. You can also check the SPF records of the incoming mail's domain using the [SPF Record Testing Tools](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can look into raw headers at GMail (top right menu -> Show original).

Usually there is a line or two, explaining why Google thinks your message is SPAM, if the problem is in the SPF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SRS ([Sender Rewriting Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme)) to avoid forwarded E-Mails classified as SPAM.

Here's a tutorial on how to setup SRS with postfix on Ubuntu: http://www.ameir.net/blog/archives/71-installing-srs-extensions-on-postfix-ubuntudebian.html

Summarized:

1. Install [pfixtools](https://github.com/Fruneau/pfixtools)
2. Set up the secret file and whitelisted addresses
3. Add pfixtools to the postfix configuration